What is the importance of the largest eigenvalue / spectral radius of a symmetric positive matrix being equal to 1? Particularly in attention.
It is often said, that if the spectral radius of a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is equal to $1$, the matrix has "regularizing" properties for the matrix product $\boldsymbol{Ax}$ for a vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ and for $\boldsymbol{AB}$ for a matrix $\boldsymbol{B}$. Why is this the case? Is it simply because the operator norm is less than $1$, so the norm of the products cannot increase or are there any other important properties, particularly for numerical mathematics?
Added context:
In the self-attention mechanism, the attention matrix after softmax operation has this property. I am interested in understanding if the spectral radius less equal to 1 is crucial in this case or if there is related concepts in other algorithms / topics.

The context is critical. If you add a specific example or two, then it is much more likely that your question can be answered completely.

Thanks for the comment @CarlChristian.
I edited the question.

I think that you need to be more specific. I searched for the key words that you provided, but found little evidence to suggest that attention matrices are usually symmetric or positive definite. This does mean that you are wrong, but it would be useful if you provided specific references to to some of the papers that use the term "regularizing" when discussing matrices with spectral norm equal to 1.

First of all, $\rho(\mathbf{A}) < 1$ doesn't mean $\lVert \mathbf{Ax} \rVert < \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert$, an example is $\mathbf{A} = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & r^{-1}\\ r &0\end{matrix}\right)$, $v = \mathbf{e_1}$, $\mathbf{Ax} = r\mathbf{e_2}$, if $r > 1$ then $\lVert \mathbf{Ax}\rVert > \mathbf{x}$. This is only applied to Hermitian $\mathbf{A}$.
Secondly, here are some important properties of the spectral radius

$\rho(\mathbf{A}) \leq \lVert\mathbf{A}^k\rVert^{\frac{1}{k}}$,
$\;\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lVert\mathbf{A}^k\rVert^{\frac{1}{k}} = \rho(\mathbf{A})$ for any norm
$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{A}^k = 0$ iif $\rho(\mathbf{A}) < 1$, $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{A}^k = \infty$ iif $\rho(\mathbf{A}) > 1$
The iterative method $\mathbf{Mx}_{n+1} = \mathbf{Nx}_n + \mathbf{b}$ is convergent iif $\rho(\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{N}) < 1$

The above method is also known as the splitting method, since if you let $\mathbf{A = M - N}$, then the equation
$$\mathbf{Ax = b}$$
can be solved iteratively by the method, provided that $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{N}$ satisfy the given condition
